# How do you save and retrieve a Key/IV pair securely?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, cryptography, rijndaelmanaged

I'm using VB.Net's `RijndaelManaged` (RM) to encrypt files, using the `RM.GenerateKey` and `RM.GenerateIV` methods to generate the Key and IV and encrypting the file using the `CryptoStream` class.  I'm planning on saving this Key and IV to a file and want to make sure I'm doing it the right way.  I am combining the IV+Key, and encrypting that with my RSA Public key and writing it out to a file.  Then, to decrypt I use the RSA Private key on this file to get the IV+Key, split them up and set RM.Key and RM.IV to these values and run the decryptor.

Is this the best method to accomplish this, or is there a preferred method for saving the IV & Key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the general idea. The IV does not need to be kept secret, however. Only the "secret key" is secret.

You might consider using a standard like S/MIME (or its underlying Cryptographic Message Syntax) for your file format. I'm not sure if Bouncycastle has ported their S/MIME (or PGP) libraries to .NET, or if .NET has S/MIME support built-in, but there is likely to be a free library available for your platform. A widely used open source library like this has probably been tested and scrutinized more closely than you'll be able to do yourself, and they implement protocols designed by experts in cryptography so your don't have to wonder what pitfalls you've overlooked.

The model you've described is similar to S/MIME's "KeyTransRecipientInfo" method for key exchange. A symmetric key is generated to encrypt the data, then that key is encrypted with the public key of each intended recipient. The encrypted key and the IV (which is not encrypted in this standard) are bundled with information about the algorithms used in a CMS structure. The encrypted data can be included in the same bundle, or be in an separate file.

PGP has mode that is an essentially equivalent.